# iBeaconGap Cordova Plugin based on RadiusNetwork Android Library

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I'm trying to use the following [iBeaconGap cordova plugin](https://github.com/TheMattRay/iBeaconGap) which is a wrapper for the RadiusNetworks Android iBeacons Library. My phone is LE bluetooth ready and detects my beacons with the RadiusNetwork Detector app from the play store.

But adding it to my plain cordova projects leads to the following log message: "attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.tecalliance.lucidbeacon/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}".
It looks like its origin is the [Callback.java](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/blob/master/src/main/java/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/service/Callback.java) class from RadiusNetworks.

The plugin installer has correctly updated the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" 
         android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">

         <meta-data android:name="background" android:value="true" />
         <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="com.thinketg.plugin.ibeacongap.DID_RANGING" />
            <action android:name="com.thinketg.plugin.ibeacongap.DID_MONITORING" />
         </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" 
         android:isolatedProcess="false" android:label="iBeacon" 
         android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService" />

<service android:enabled="true"   
         android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">

         <meta-data android:name="background" android:value="true" />
         <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="com.thinketg.plugin.ibeacongap.DID_RANGING" />
            <action android:name="com.thinketg.plugin.ibeacongap.DID_MONITORING" />
         </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

I use the plugin suggested on github, but neither gotBeacons() nor failedGettingBeacons() gets called.

```
function startBeaconScans() {
    iBeaconGap.getBeacons(gotBeacons, failedGettingBeacons);
}
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: While I don't why your setup isn't working, I can say that the "attempting callback via intent" log line you see is a normal part of the background IBeaconService communicating with the app.